# attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.TextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(android.view.TextureView$SurfaceTextureListener)'

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm getting this error when using the library RNCamera

> attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.view.TextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(android.view.TextureView$SurfaceTextureListener)'
> on a null object reference

---

[image]

I reinstall the library but still getting this error. This error occurs when I updated my RN from 0.62.2 to 0.66.1. Thank you for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by running `cd android && ./gradlew clean`